# Reading the status of the screen

Tags: shell-script, xrandr, monitors

I used to read the status of rotation of my screen with this command in fedora 22:

```
status=$(xrandr --verbose | grep LVDS1 | awk '{print $6}'
```

and the output would be something like `noraml` or `inverted` etc.
This worked even when I was sharing screen with some other monitors/projectors. After updating to fedora 23, each time that I connect the laptop to an external monitor or projector the information on that line of `xrandr` changes slightly and the `$6` part goes to show the `(normal` part of the `(normal left inverted right x axis y axis)` which does not give me any information and I have to change the `$6` to `$5` to get the status of the monitor. I have patched the problem by testing the first character and if it is `(` it uses the other output. that is,

```
testvalue=$(xrandr --verbose | grep LVDS1 | awk '{print $6}')
[ ${testvalue:0:1} == "(" ] && status=$(xrandr --verbose | grep LVDS1 | awk '{print $5}') || status=$(xrandr --verbose | grep LVDS1 | awk '{print $6}')
```

This gets the job done for the moment. **My question is how do I fix this in a more stable way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xrandr | awk -F'(' '/^LVDS1/{ split($2,a," "); print a[3]}'
```

xrandr prints this line without --verbose.

Use '(' as filed separator

Only look at lines that match /^LVDS1/

Split the second field into an array (named a) using " " as separator

Finally print the third element of a